# adress mapping not found when using class with Hibernate JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpql

```
@entity class Emp { 
   @ElementCollection @Collection table(name=adress); 
   List <Address> adress
}
```

I have one class Emp in which Address is collection table. Now I want to write hql query to delete the list of record from address table which is not entity table.

So I write

```
Typedquery query=entitymanager.createquery (delete from address where emp id in (:list of id); Int I= query.executeUpdate():
```

Then I get error which say address mapping not found syntax error exception

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: what type of object is stored in field `address`??? and where is the entity? and where is `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Emp is entity class and address is embeddebl class . I want to perform delete on operation on collection table this is pure annotation based

Comment: an embeddable doesn't exist in its own right (clue in its name). You delete an entity. Retrieve the entity and delete objects from the collection field.

Comment: Can't i delete collection table adress content

Comment: By query, NO, as already said. By deleting elements from a Collection, clearly

Comment: How to delete elements from collection?

Comment: Can you actually read what I put? *Retrieve the entity and delete objects from the collection field.* So do a find of the Entity in question, and delete elements from the Collection field. How hard is that?